# Applying masks to image in pytorch

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, pytorch

I have tensor with images, which has shape `[b, c, h, w]`, where

- b - batch,
- c - channels,
- w - width,
- h - height,

for example tensor has shape `[4, 3, 275, 275]`; and I have tensor with masks from neural network, which has shape `[b, n, h, w]`, where

- b - batch,
- n - num of detections,
- h,
- w - height and width respectively.

Also I have list of colors for mask with length equal num of detections, where every element is tuple of tensors with single number like `colors[0]=(tensor(0), tensor(0), tensor(0))`. How I can apply all colors to images to avoid for loops?
Right now I have double loop:

```
for masks_, img_to_draw_ in zip(masks, img_to_draw):
    for mask, color in zip(masks_, colors_):
        img_to_draw_[:, mask] = color[:, None]
    imgs.append(img_to_draw_)
```

Maybe exist a way to vectorized this operation? At least the inner loop.